# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column error on laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my laravel application I have following function.

This will list down my users in a datatable inside a vue component and users are allowed to filter the records by certain parameters.

```
public function execute()
    {
        return User::selectRaw('users.id as id, users.first_name as first_name, users.last_name as last_name, users.country_id as country_id, users.email as email')
            ->selectRaw('departments.name as department_name, departments.department_type_id as department_type_id')
            ->selectRaw('project_specific_job_titles.title as job_title')
            ->selectRaw('min(project_track_records.id) as project_user_id')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(
                DISTINCT(IF(
                    certificate_project_specific_job_title.certificate_id IS NOT NULL
                    AND certificate_project_specific_job_title.mandatory = 1,
                    certificate_project_specific_job_title.certificate_id,
                    null
                ))
            ) AS available_certificate_count')
            ->selectRaw('(
                SELECT count(*) from
                    (
                        SELECT certificate_project_specific_job_title.certificate_id from certificate_project_specific_job_title
                        WHERE certificate_project_specific_job_title.project_specific_job_title_id=project_track_records.project_specific_job_title_id
                        AND certificate_project_specific_job_title.mandatory = 1
                    ) as certificate_count_sub_query
                ) as certificate_count
            ')
            ->leftJoin('certificate_user', 'certificate_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('project_track_records', 'project_track_records.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('certificate_project_specific_job_title', function ($join) {
                $join->on( 'certificate_project_specific_job_title.certificate_id', '=', 'certificate_user.certificate_id')
                    ->whereRaw('certificate_project_specific_job_title.project_specific_job_title_id=project_track_records.project_specific_job_title_id');
            })
            ->leftjoin('project_specific_job_titles', 'project_specific_job_titles.id', '=', 'project_track_records.project_specific_job_title_id')
            ->leftJoin('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'project_specific_job_titles.department_id')
            ->whereNull('project_track_records.deleted_at')
            ->whereNotNull('project_track_records.accepted_at')
            ->where('users.first_name', '<>', '')
            ->where('users.last_name', '<>', '')
            ->groupBy('users.id','project_track_records.project_specific_job_title_id')
            ->when(request('search_text'), function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->whereRaw("CONCAT_WS(' ', `first_name`, `last_name`) like '%".request('search_text')."%'");
                });
            })
            ->when(request('employee_type'), function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('users.is_subcontractor', request('employee_type'));
            })
            ->when(request('nationality'), function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('users.country_id', request('nationality'));
            });
    }
```

But every time when I try to run this it gives me an sql error saying,

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'project_track_records.project_specific_job_title_id'

In my database, inside my `project_track_records` table I have `project_specific_job_title_id` column and even it contains data..

I even tried flushing my database and running migrations multiple times but this kept giving me unknown column error and I'm struggling to find the mistake I'm doing there...

My laravel version is 8.83.9 and php version is 8.1.4

Comment: Either a case sensitivity issue, or a typo, or your code runs on a database where this table does not have this column.

Comment: You can try to dump the row query with `->toSql()` and debug the sql

Comment: @Ross_102 then it gives me Error
Call to a member function projectSpecificExpiresSoonCount() on string

Comment: No idea. Are you doing : `$sqlQuery = User::selectRaw...->toSql();dd($sqlQuery);`

Comment: The best way to debug this is to use ->toSql() and copy/paste into phpmyadmin your query. Replace your missing values with real ID's from your table in case it needs to